# Disable encryption on android nougat greyed out

Tags: security

I updated my Lenovo k6 power to android nougat after reset it automatically encrypts device

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Maybe your OEM doesn't want you to disable encryption. Or set up a lock screen password, and then try it (I saw somewhere that it worked a long time ago, a Reddit post IIRC)

Comment: Why do you want to disable encryption? Anyhow, you need to find a compatible kernel for your device which disables forced encryption on boot and then flash it, do factory reset and you're good to go. // I can't help with how to find that kernel or how to flash it. That's your job. :-) // You can alternatively edit your stock kernel's image ([e.g.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-z/development/disable-stock-kernals-force-encrypt-t3467742)).

Comment: Fewer CPU operations should mean a longer lasting battery charge and consequently total battery life. Besides, in my case, it would have been nice if they had asked first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that happened to me too (but on samsung galaxy S7) and it seems like that is an new security option and I disabled it by unchecking the ask for password before booting in the setup. I didnt ever heard of a way to disable encryption without resetting.

Comment: If i reset my device it forces encryption by default without any pin

Comment: I did that (KNOX is tripped now)Developer Settings>OEM lock off>rooted maybe thats the difference I also reinstalled the stock rom and pressed than volume down + power off when a blue screen appeared with the erasing sign. But to be honest I dont know and when I press encrypt it reboots and im still unencrypted so it may be the root process. (i flashed CF auto root)

Comment: Thnx for the help